# Nginx server degrades over the course of a day

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I am experiencing issues daily with my server slowing down. I believe that it is an issue with nginx or php-fpm giving up at some point and not gracefully recovering. I will include any information that can help. I will start with my nginx and php-fpm settings. Please let me know if there is anything else that would be helpful to post here. I do use cloudflare if that might help in the diagnosis.

I would also take suggestion on how to figure out why if the below information isn't enough.

The website is [here](https://practiscore.com)

**Edit:**
It seems as though every request starts to use up the set amount of resources that nignx or php can use but doesn't free them. My monitoring and `top` does not show a spike in cpu or memory when the server start to respond slowly. At some point the slowness hits the timeout and returns a 5XX error.

I have a server hosted on linode. It's specs are:

```
8 GB RAM
6 CPU Cores
192 GB SSD Storage
8 TB Transfer
40 Gbps Network In
1000 Mbps Network Out
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes 6;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##
    # set client body size to 2M #  
    client_max_body_size 50M;

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
# added cbt, cht, st -- kt was there
keepalive_timeout 5;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

default_type application/octet-stream;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

##
# Logging Settings
##
log_format cf_custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                '$http_cf_ray';

#access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
#error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 5;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
# Gzip the following types of requests/files
gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml  image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;

##
# nginx-naxsi config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
# nginx-passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
##

#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

# Cloudflare
set_real_ip_from 199.27.128.0/21;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20; 
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;        
}
```

php-fpm.conf

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5/fpm.log
log_level = debug 
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10
process.max = 128
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

www.conf

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

pm = ondemand

pm.max_children = 26

pm.start_servers = 8

pm.min_spare_servers = 5

pm.max_spare_servers = 11

pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

pm.max_requests = 50
slowlog = /var/log/php5/slow.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 10s
request_terminate_timeout = 360s
;rlimit_files = 1024
rlimit_core = unlimited

chdir = /
```

top

```
top - 14:39:10 up  1:04,  2 users,  load average: 1.47, 1.28, 1.28
Tasks: 187 total,   3 running, 183 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 16.0 us,  4.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.1 st
KiB Mem:   8206476 total,  7661580 used,   544896 free,  2386564 buffers
KiB Swap:   524284 total,     1328 used,   522956 free.   680268 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 1653 root      20   0  284736  41136  15176 S   6.3  0.5   0:00.19 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1659 root      20   0  285048  42040  15672 S   6.3  0.5   0:00.19 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1668 root      20   0  285048  42076  15704 S   6.3  0.5   0:00.19 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1676 root      20   0  285048  41956  15588 S   6.3  0.5   0:00.19 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1645 root      20   0  284732  41060  15108 S   6.0  0.5   0:00.18 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1649 root      20   0  284732  41480  15520 S   6.0  0.5   0:00.18 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1656 root      20   0  284736  41336  15376 S   6.0  0.5   0:00.18 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1664 root      20   0  284736  41320  15360 S   6.0  0.5   0:00.18 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1680 root      20   0  284736  41332  15368 S   6.0  0.5   0:00.18 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1684 root      20   0  280172  38288  14816 R   5.3  0.5   0:00.16 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 1222 www-data  20   0  351712  80236  64044 S   4.3  1.0   0:00.64 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 1065 www-data  20   0  351680  79912  63768 S   3.7  1.0   0:00.79 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 1215 www-data  20   0  351548  68972  52844 S   3.7  0.8   0:00.58 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 1484 www-data  20   0  349536  65116  49748 S   3.7  0.8   0:00.23 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  502 www-data  20   0  351604  69484  53932 S   2.7  0.8   0:01.26 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 1496 www-data  20   0  349532  65248  49748 S   2.7  0.8   0:00.23 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
31105 www-data  20   0  351776  81428  65260 S   2.7  1.0   0:02.92 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 3194 www-data  20   0   88216   7788   4440 S   2.3  0.1   0:09.70 nginx                                                                                                                                                                                                                
31652 www-data  20   0  352180  82120  65644 S   2.3  1.0   0:02.73 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  512 www-data  20   0  347204  71160  57300 S   2.0  0.9   0:01.14 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  980 www-data  20   0  351712  80484  64300 S   2.0  1.0   0:00.82 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 1639 root      20   0  285048  41864  15492 S   2.0  0.5   0:00.19 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
31275 www-data  20   0  349020  78496  64812 S   2.0  1.0   0:03.20 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
32114 www-data  20   0  351628  78468  62316 S   2.0  1.0   0:01.93 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  588 www-data  20   0  352940  82800  66476 S   1.7  1.0   0:01.64 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
30959 www-data  20   0  351816  83404  67180 S   1.7  1.0   0:03.43 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
31736 www-data  20   0  349788  68604  54188 S   1.7  0.8   0:02.50 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 3129 mysql     20   0 3441720 208516  11144 S   1.3  2.5   1:23.69 mysqld                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  840 www-data  20   0  349788  76684  62444 R   1.0  0.9   0:00.84 php5-fpm                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 3617 root      20   0  560496  12724   5328 S   0.7  0.2   0:21.73 fail2ban-server                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:04.87 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 1462 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:03.17 kworker/4:1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 1635 root      20   0  285048  41928  15556 S   0.3  0.5   0:00.19 php5                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 3299 root      20   0  279628  37576  14760 S   0.3  0.5   0:11.20 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3301 root      20   0  279628  37616  14800 S   0.3  0.5   0:11.24 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3304 root      20   0  279628  37652  14840 S   0.3  0.5   0:11.16 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3305 root      20   0  279628  37528  14712 S   0.3  0.5   0:11.04 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3307 root      20   0  279628  37620  14804 S   0.3  0.5   0:11.06 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3309 root      20   0  279628  37696  14880 S   0.3  0.5   0:11.27 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3313 root      20   0  278344  36640  15032 S   0.3  0.4   0:10.60 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3314 root      20   0  278344  36560  14952 S   0.3  0.4   0:10.57 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3319 root      20   0  278344  36632  15024 S   0.3  0.4   0:10.63 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 3333 root      20   0  278344  36672  15068 S   0.3  0.4   0:10.41 php                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    1 root      20   0   33652   4196   2724 S   0.0  0.1   0:03.96 init                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.17 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.13 kworker/u12:0                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 migration/0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.05 migration/1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   13 root       0 -20       0
```

iostat

```
Linux 4.1.5-x86_64-linode61 (localhost)     09/29/2015  _x86_64_    (6 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          16.05    0.00    5.52    0.12    0.12   78.19

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda             74.76       321.33       285.55    3117199    2770120
xvdb              0.02         0.06         0.14        572       1336
```

iostat -x 1 -- when slow

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    7.00     0.00    28.00     8.00     0.00    0.43    0.00    0.43   0.57   0.40
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          25.84    0.00    8.22    0.00    0.17   65.77

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00    55.00    0.00   10.00     0.00   264.00    52.80     0.00    0.40    0.00    0.40   0.30   0.30
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.68    0.00    4.17    0.00    0.00   87.15

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          10.18    0.00    5.01    0.00    0.00   84.81

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          18.06    0.00    5.52    0.00    0.00   76.42

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    3.00     0.00    12.00     8.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          17.47    0.00    6.82    0.00    0.17   75.54

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    7.00     0.00    28.00     8.00     0.00    0.43    0.00    0.43   0.43   0.30
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          15.55    0.00    3.34    0.00    0.00   81.10

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00   105.00    0.00   21.00     0.00   696.00    66.29     0.00    0.14    0.00    0.14   0.19   0.40
xvdb              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: define *"slow down"*. From the data above server seems to be almost idle.

Comment: @drookie The time for the page to load starts to increase to the point that it hits the timeout limit which returns a 5XX error.

Comment: Is top snapshot taken at the moment of time when server is that slow ?

Comment: @drookie No, but I have checked when the server is slow and my linode monitor and `top` doesn't show a spike in cpu, memory, or any other metric.

Comment: what about disks and %busy ?

Comment: @drookie Disk show no spikes on i/o. I am not sure how to see %busy.

Comment: using `iostat` of course.

Comment: Plus, tell me what do you do to restore performance.

Comment: @drookie server restart or nignx and php-fpm restart.

Comment: `iostat -x 1` needed, 6-8 lines from the middle of the output, while the server is slow.

Comment: seems like a network issue to me if all else is well -- capture tcpdump when your server is slow - check netstat , ifconfig to see if there are dropped packets